# converting foldl expression to foldr for a finite list

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, fold

So I encountered this question where I need to determine if it is possible to convert the following strip into a foldr when xs is a finite list.

`foldl f 0 xs where f x y = y - x`

I tried to convert it applying the definition of foldr but it seems it does not work in any way. So my guess would be it is not possible. If that is true, could you please give me a reasonable justification that the conversion to foldr expression is impossible?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hint: write `foldl` itself in terms of `foldr`.

Comment: 2nd Hint: the issue you run into is that the order is reversed (and `-` is not commutative) - so you have to fix it - you are probably not allowed to use `reverse` but maybe you've seen before that using *continuations* is reversing stuff ... so instead of passing a number as an accumulator pass a function *number -> result* ...